# Rails: Show only items belonging to current model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, associations

I have a Documents controller, model & view and a DocumentTypes controller, model & view. A document `has_and_belongs_to_many` DocumentTypes and a DocumentType `has_and_belongs_to_many` Documents. I have a form on the Documents index template in which, when adding a new document, I set the document_type_id equal to whatever document type you select from a dropdown. It look as so:

```
<%= form_for Project.new, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= select_tag "document[document_type_id][]", options_from_collection_for_select(DocumentType.find(:all), "id", "title") %>
<% end %>
```

All I'm trying to do next is list only the documents assigned to the current document type on the document type show page. I currently just have this:

```
// Controller
def show
    ...
    @documents = Document.find(:all)
end

// View
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

I'm not entirely sure that the document_type_id is getting set correctly upon adding a new document, so that very well could be my problem. I've tried using `.where` like: `@documents = Document.where(:document_type_id => 1)` but that just gives me a blank list when viewed in the browser.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minimal passing example.
It also demonstrates a good quick way to use tests to play around with the code until you have what you want:

```
> rails new so20794896
> cd so20794896
> rails g scaffold documents
> rails g scaffold document_types
> rails g migration create_document_types_documents document_id:integer document_type_id:integer
> rake db:migrate
```

**edit app/models/document.rb**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :document_types
end
```

**edit app/models/document_type.rb**

```
class DocumentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
end
```

**edit test/models/document_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class DocumentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "find by document type" do
    one = documents(:one)
    doc_type = document_types(:two)
    one.document_types << doc_type
    one.save!

    found_docs = DocumentType.find(doc_type.id).documents
    assert_equal one, found_docs.first
    assert_equal 1, found_docs.length
  end
end
```

And then run the test via:

```
> rake test TEST=test/unit/document_test.rb
```

And check out `log/test.log` for the query that this issues, like:

```
SELECT "document_types".* FROM "document_types" INNER JOIN "document_types_documents" 
  ON "document_types"."id" = "document_types_documents"."document_type_id" 
  WHERE "document_types_documents"."document_id" = ?  [["document_id", 980190962]]
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer. My associations are exactly as you have shown above already. I tried the test, but it didn't really give me anything that I needed. I basically now need to figure out why, when using something like `<% @document_type.documents.each do |document| %>test<% end %>`, it doesn't list out "test" at all. I'm assuming the document_type_id is not getting saved correctly when adding a new document.

Comment: I'm using this to select the document type when adding a new document: <%= select_tag "document[document_type_id][]", options_from_collection_for_select(DocumentType.find(:all), "id", "title") %>

Comment: `document_type_id` isn't a property of the `document` model, so why not just name the select `document_type_id` and grab that param directly? I suggest having a controller test that ensures that the controller action is correctly picking the right param and using it, and then you can look in the logs to ensure that that param is being sent from the view.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you didn't set up relation very well .
If your Document belongs to Document Type then relation should be like

```
Document belongs_to document_type
```

And add document_type_id to documents table.

then your query will work .

If you really want has_and_belongs_to_many relation , then you have to setup intermediate table.like

```
Document has_and_belongs_to_many document_types through: document_type_relation
DocumentType has_and_belongs_to_many documents through: document_type_relation
```

DocumentTypeRelation will have document_id and document_type_id 
then you can query on DocumentTypeRelation to find all Documents with specific Document Type.

Comment: I actually do have a DocumentTypesDocuments table. It looks like this:

`class AddDocumentTypesDocumentsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   create_table :document_types_documents do |t|
     t.integer :document_type_id
     t.integer :document_id
 end
  end

  def down
   drop_table :document_types_documents
  end
end`

Comment: Sorry, edited to what the connecting table looks like.

Comment: then if you want to find documents assigned to current document type, simply find that document type . say doc_type = DocumentType.find(1), and use doc_type.documents .